# Comment traduire « About this document » (nom d'une section d'un document) ?

Tags: traduction, vocabulaire, anglais, terminologie

Quelles sont les manières les plus usuelles de traduire le nom d'une section d'un document qu'on nomme « about this document » ?

Comment: Le contexte semble inexistant ; il faudrait des précisions.

Comment: Il est souvent difficile de traduire "legacy", quand cela qualifie un système éprouvé en cours de remplacement, ça peut donner "existant", "ancien" ou plus rarement "désuet".

Comment: @s.H.a.R.p.R.i.F.t "Historique" sans plus de précision? Par déduction, on peut pense que c'est l'historique du document, et ne pas ajouter de précision permet de ne pas préjuger de comment cet historique est maintenu? (sur la base de _section qui donne des informations sur le document, des dates, des versions etc_).

Comment: Sans plus de précisions sur le contenu de la section, je proposerai "Avant-propos" (*foreword*) pour traduire *About this document*, mais il manque évidemment l'aspect *Legacy* qu'on peut combiner avec la proposition de @Frank : "Avant-Propos et historique du document".

Comment: @Graffito Ca pourrait marcher, si ladite section est _au début_ du document? Ce qui est peut-être le cas?

Comment: @s.H.a.R.p.R.i.F.t "Données annexes/supplémentaires à propos de ce document"?

Comment: Intéressant: «en d'autres mots» sonnes comme un anglicisme. Je vois, néanmoins, que c'est correct, bien qu'«En d'autres termes» soit plus commun.

Comment: You chose historique after saying it was wrong here. The comments with it were removed by the mod.

Comment: Well, something is up because the mods said my two flags were helpful and now they say pending. See for yourself: https://french.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/9299 You might try being more polite and less aggressive. How dare you say I'm trolling. Really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si la section est placée au début et sert à résumer le document ou a donner des informations utiles avant d'aborder sa lecture :

> ***À propos de ce document
>
> Note préalable
>
> Préambule***

Si la section est destinée à donner des informations sur l'évolution du document dans le temps :

> ***Suivi du document
>
> Données de suivi***
> ainsi que la [réponse déjà proposée](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/53417/1109) (+1).

Comment: De bonnes suggestions. La question de la position et de la fonction ne fait plus partie de ma question mais c'est intéressant. Note qu'on peut trouver des cas où cet ordre est différent, par exemple [ici](https://www.epfl.ch/campus/library/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/Bibliotheque_EPFL_Guide_Rational_Bibliographic.pdf), ou il y a double-emploi avec préambule et où ça apparaît avant même ce dernier.

Answer (score 2):

Je pencherais vers "**Historique de ce document**". Cette formulation est employée couramment et apparaît dans de nombreux sites.